# Submenu slidesout on other menu items on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu for my wordpress sidebar, but I have a issue with the sub-menu, because when it opens it's shown on the main menu items.

How can I make the menu to expand so that the menu and submenu items will be visible and not one on the other?

`here is the link to code` [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Ricods/pen/xyJyYm/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` from your `ul.sub-menu` class.